# How to extract same parts of file name with different patterns?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, dictionary

I have the following file name formats:

```
2020-01-05-ABC1111_001.jpg
2020_02_06_B444444_MN_004.jpg
2020_03_20_KUKU44223222-STAFF_005.jpg
2020-04-03-LULU4444211-MN_018.jpg
```

Most (99%) of the files are of the following format:

```
2020_04_03_LULU4444211_018.jpg
```

And I just use `rsplit("_", 2)` and get what I need.

Where the first part is date, second is and ID, MN or STAFF, page number.

How to build a good regex or split function to somehow split it to date, id, and page?

From all the above examples I would like to get:

```
{
"2020-01-05-ABC1111_001.jpg": {"date": 2020-01-05, "id": ABC1111, "page_num": 1},
"2020_02_06_B444444_MN_004.jpg": {"date": 2020_02_06, "id": B444444, "page_num": 4},
"2020_03_20_KUKU44223222-STAFF_005.jpg": {"date": 2020_03_20, "id": KUKU44223222, "page_num": 5},
"2020-04-03-LULU4444211-MN_018.jpg": {"date": 2020-04-03, "id": LULU4444211, "page_num": 18}
}
```

I am have tried `rsplit`, I know there is an annotation option + Spacy NER model but maybe there is another way to do it more simply?

Comment: Regex, something along the lines of `'(\d{4}[-_]\d{2}[-_]\d[2})[-_](.*?)[-_](\d+)\.jpg'`might get you parts that you can refine.

Comment: Why downvoting a good question with brilliant answers?

Comment: curious isn't it ... 2 ppl answered and _still_ the question has no upvote. I wondr why ... maybe because you never showed any [mre]  and what you did to solve it yourself...

Comment: Dear @PatrickArtner I have mentioned the techniques I have used, the regex in the accepted answer is not trivial at all. Have a look on the reputation of the guy who answered - 400K, and I wonder why, maybe because the question isn't trivial? 
Reread the question and you will see that I explained what I did.

Comment: thats why I did not downvote and gave you a tip on how to do it. Compare my hint above with Wiktors result. Wiktor is _the_ Regex answerer here,  and he also close/dupecloses things he knows are dupe,wich your question is not. But your questions - in my humble opinion, it is also _FAR_ from a "good question".

Comment: Dear @PatrickArtner thanks, I will take into consideration and will try my best to make my questions more informative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use code like

```
import re

strings = ['2020-01-05-ABC1111_001.jpg','2020_02_06_B444444_MN_004.jpg','2020_03_20_KUKU44223222-STAFF_005.jpg','2020-04-03-LULU4444211-MN_018.jpg']
rx = re.compile(r'(?P<date>\d{4}[-_]\d{2}[-_]\d{2})[-_](?P<id>[^_-]+)(?:[_-](?:MN|STAFF))?[_-](?P<page_num>\d+)')

d = {}
for s in strings:
    m = rx.search(s)
    if m:
        d[s] = m.groupdict()

print(d)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/KFABNV), yielding

```
{'2020-01-05-ABC1111_001.jpg': {'date': '2020-01-05', 'id': 'ABC1111', 'page_num': '001'}, '2020_02_06_B444444_MN_004.jpg': {'date': '2020_02_06', 'id': 'B444444', 'page_num': '004'}, '2020_03_20_KUKU44223222-STAFF_005.jpg': {'date': '2020_03_20', 'id': 'KUKU44223222', 'page_num': '005'}, '2020-04-03-LULU4444211-MN_018.jpg': {'date': '2020-04-03', 'id': 'LULU4444211', 'page_num': '018'}}
```

Note the regex used contains named capturing groups so that you could get access to `.groupdict()` after  a match is found, it looks like

```
(?P<date>\d{4}[-_]\d{2}[-_]\d{2})[-_](?P<id>[^_-]+)(?:[_-](?:MN|STAFF))?[_-](?P<page_num>\d+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xzbB64/1).

**Regex details**

- `(?P<date>\d{4}[-_]\d{2}[-_]\d{2})` - Group "date": 4 digits, `_` or `-`, 2 digits, `_` or `-` and then again 2 digits
- `[-_]` - a hyphen or underscore
- `(?P<id>[^_-]+)` - Group "id": 1 or more chars other than `-` and `_`
- `(?:[_-](?:MN|STAFF))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching `-` or `_` and then `MN` or `STAFF`
- `[_-]` - a `-` or `_`
- `(?P<page_num>\d+)` - Group "page_num": 1 or more digits.

Answer (score 2):

Regexp:

```
(\d{4}[-_]\d{2}[-_]\d{2})[-_](.*)[-_](\d+)\.[a-zA-Z]+
```

It contains three regexp groups:

1. date
2. id
3. page number

Explanation:

```
(\d{4}[-_]\d{2}[-_]\d{2}) # date (yyyy-mm-dd or yyyy_mm_dd) - group 1
[-_] # separator (dash or underscore)
(.+) # id (any character) - group 2
[-_] # separator
(\d+) # page number - group 3
\.[a-zA-Z]+ # file extension
```

[image: Regexp result]

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/IPF7QE/1

You can read groups in Python this way:

```
if match := re.search(regexp, text_line, re.IGNORECASE):
  date = match.group(1)
  id = match.group(2)
  page_number = match.group(3)
```